# Is it possible to cover $\mathbb{N}$ with a finite number of equivalence classes of different modules?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Is the following statement is true or false?

> There are  numbers $a_{1},\ a_{2}, \ldots,a_{n}$  and $r_{1},\ r_{2},
>  \ldots , r_{n}$ in $\mathbb{N}$ where $a_{i}$'s are different and $a_{i}\neq 0$ for each $i=1,2,\ldots, n,$ such that if we define
>   $$K_{i}=\left\{m \in \mathbb{N}\ : \ m\cong a_{i} \left(\mbox{mod}\
>  r_{i}\right) \right \} \ \ \mbox{for each} \ \ i=1,2,\ldots, n,$$ then
>   $\mathbb{N}=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}K_{i}$.

**Remark:** I think the statement is false, I tried to prove but my attempts have failed. My idea is to build a number that is not congruent to $a_{i}$ module $r_{i}$ for each $i=1,2,\ldots, n$, but I do not know how to do it.

Comment: It is true. There is a large literature on [Covering Systems of Congruences.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_system#Systems_of_odd_moduli)

Comment: You are lacking some conditions or this is trivial. Presumably you want the $r_i$ to be different. Is there something else that is missing? Anyway, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_system).

Comment: There may be equal numbers $r_{i}$, but the $a_i$ are diferent, also $a_i \neq 0$ for each $i=1,2, \ldots, n.$

Comment: As written, this is clearly false. Take $m = r_1 r_2 \dots r_n$. Then $m \equiv 0 \bmod r_i$ for all $i$, and you specified that the $a_i$ aren't equal to zero (by this I assume that you meant they weren't $0 \bmod r_i$). Are you sure this is what you meant to ask?

Comment: Yes, Qiaochu Yuan, your answer is what I expected, thanks.